# Prove that in $\mathbb R$, the integral of the derivative of an integrable function is $0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

$\quad$ Let $f$ be a differentiable function in $\mathbb R$, and $f$ is also a Lebesgue integrable function in $\mathbb R$. Let $f'$ be a Lebesgue integrable function in $\mathbb R$, too. How to prove that:

$$\int_{\mathbb R}f'(x)\mathrm dx=0$$

$\quad$ My intuition tells me that when a function is integrable over the whole space, that is, when its integral is finite, the value of the function always starts at $0$ and ends at $0$. The way up is the way down, so the derivative's integration is $0$. But I know that even if the function is integrable on the whole space, it doesn't have to be $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$$ This function is not necessarily an absolutely continuous function, so there seems to be no direct relationship between the integral of its derivative and the original function in my mind. I can't think any more. Is there any way to deal with this problem?

Any discussion and suggestions are welcome!

Edit:
According to PhoemueX, I learned that $f$ is absolutely continuous over any interval $[a,b]$.

Based on Kurt G's answers and Stefan's hints, I understand the significance of limits there. So it seems that we can get the result without doing an odd-even decomposition.

My idea is that already known $$\int_a^bf'(x)\mathrm dx=f(b)- f(a)$$ and $f'(x)$ is integrable, so $$\lim_{a\to+\infty}\int_{-a}^0f'(x)\mathrm dx,\quad\lim_{b\to+\infty}\int_0^bf'(x)\mathrm dx$$ both exist, so $$\lim_{a\to+\infty}(f(0)- f(-a)),\quad\lim_{b\to+\infty}(f(b)- f(0))$$ both exist, therefore $f(\pm\infty)$ both exist. Then according to $f$ being integrable, $f(\pm\infty)$ can only be $0$, so we get the final conclusion.

Comment: Your assumptions do in fact imply that f is absolutely continuous. See theorem 7.21 in Rudin's "real and complex analysis". Can you take it from there?

Comment: It was very enlightening to me! However, can I take $$\int_{\mathbb R}f'(x)\mathrm dx=\lim_{a\to-\infty,b\to+\infty}\left(f(b)-f(a)\right)$$ This limit does not necessarily seem to exist. What more explanation should be needed? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why on earth does this have 3 close votes?

Comment: What's that mean?

Comment: @Stefan If you are able to see the edit history, the question was initially asked as a typical problem statement question. Much of what you see here now had been added in later edits.

Comment: @daidaitx: People with high enough reputation can vote to close a question (5 votes are needed). I saw that 3 people had voted to close and I didn't understand why.

Comment: @Divide1918: Yes, you're right, that's probably it.

Comment: It has been shown many times on this  site that integrability of  $f$ and $f'$  implies the  limits of $f$ at $\pm \infty$ exist and are $0$. So this  question is essentially a duplicate.

Comment: @geetha290krm: Why don't you help the OP out and post a link then?

Comment: @Stefan Well they don’t have the obligation to do so. In fact, no one has.

Comment: @Divide1918: Of course not. Some people are here to help, others have different motivations.

Comment: @Stefan I can see you're enjoying helping others. thx

Comment: Following Phoemmuex's hint $f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^{x}f'(t)dt \to f(0)+\int_0^{\infty} f'(t)dt$ proving that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting
$$
g(x):=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}\,,\quad h(x):=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}
$$
we can decompose $f$ into an even function $g$ plus an odd function $h\,:$
$$
f(x)=g(x)+h(x)\,.
$$
The derivative of $g$ is odd and the derivative of $h$ is even:
$$
g'(x)=-g'(-x)\,,\quad h'(x)=h'(-x)\,.
$$
Since the integral of an odd function is zero we get
$$
\int_\mathbb Rf'(x)\,dx=\int_\mathbb Rh'(x)\,dx\,.
$$
Since $h$ is even we get
$$
\int_\mathbb Rh'(x)\,dx=\lim_{a\to\infty}\big(h(a)-h(-a)\big)=\lim_{a\to\infty}2h(a)\,.
$$
If this limit were different from zero this would imply that $h$ is not integrable which is a contradiction.

Comment: Why does "limit is not zero" get "$h$ is not integrable"? As I said before, the limit of an integrable function can be not exist at infinity. In fact, you can make a function jump infinite times, maintaining the sum of these integrals still finite, which makes the limit of the integrable function at infinity nonexistent.

Comment: @daidaitx You assumed that $f$ and $f'$ are integrable. The same is true for $g,h,g',h'\,.$ Therefore the limit in that last line must exist.

Comment: @daidaitx: I think the argument is that $\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-a}^ah'(x)\,dx$ exists because $h$ is integrable. By evenness, $\int_{-a}^ah'(x)\,dx=2h(a)$. So $\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}2h(a)$ exists. Even though integrable functions need not have a limit at infinity, we know that they cannot have a non-zero limit at infinity. So, since we have shown that the limit exists, we can now conclude that the limit is zero.

Comment: @Stefan I seem to understand that $h'$ is an integrable function resulting in everything! (You seem to have missed a derivative sign)

Comment: @daidaitx: Yes, I meant that $\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-a}^ah'(x)\,dx$ exists because $h'$ is integrable.